# Cuenta no encontrada de Github en Vercel

Tags: github, nextjs, vercel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, quisiera saber si alguien de aquí ya a tenido este problema al querer desplegar un proyecto en vercel, soy nuevo en esto y quiero hacer una cuenta de vercel con mi GitHub pero me aparece este error, en mi GutHub si aparece la conexión, pero en vercel me aparece que no encuntran mi cuenta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta contactar al servicio soporte de vercel para recibir ayuda.